# unable to parse ' ' as integer in android

Tags: android, integer

I have read so many articles but still don't get it.

I have a serial data which is a String type and i want to compare it with an integer.

This is the read serial data code:

```
case MESSAGE_READ:
                int i;

                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj; 


             // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, readMessage);

                mTextView.setText(readMessage);
                String [] numbers = readMessage.split("\n");
                int [] intNumber = new int[numbers.length];
                //List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();


                for (String number : numbers) {

                    //integers.add(Integer.valueOf(number.trim()));
                    for (i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
                        intNumber[i] = Integer.valueOf(number.trim());
                        if (intNumber[i]<0 || intNumber[i]>95){
                            //Some Actions
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
```

And the LogCat shows:

```
05-06 17:28:06.919: D/BluetoothReadService(15090): connected
05-06 17:28:06.919: D/BluetoothReadService(15090): create ConnectedThread
05-06 17:28:06.929: D/BluetoothReadService(15090): setState() 2 -> 3
05-06 17:28:06.949: I/BluetoothReadService(15090): BEGIN mConnectedThread
05-06 17:28:06.969: I/HBAS(15090): MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: 3
05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 24

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 25

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 26

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 27

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 28

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 29

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 0

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 1

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 2

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 3

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 4

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 5

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 6

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 7

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 8

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 9

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 10

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 11

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 12

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 13

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 14

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 15

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 16

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 17

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 18

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 19

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 20

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 21

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 22

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 23

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 24

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 25

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 26

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 27

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 28

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 29

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 0

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 1

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 2

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 3

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 4

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 5

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 6

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 7

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 8

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 9

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 10

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 11

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 12

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 13

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 14

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 15

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 16

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 17

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 18

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 19

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 20

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 21

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 22

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 23

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 24

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 25

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 26

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 27

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 28

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 29

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 0

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 1

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 2

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 3

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 4

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 5

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 6

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 7

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 8

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 9

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 10

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 11

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 12

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 13

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 14

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 15

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 16

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 17

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 18

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 19

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 20

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 21

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 22

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 23

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 24

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 25

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 26

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 27

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 28

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 29

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 0

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 1

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 2

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 3

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 4

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 5

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 6

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 7

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 8

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 9

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 10

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 11

05-06 17:28:07.079: I/HBAS(15090): 12

05-06 17:28:07.969: I/HBAS(15090): 1
05-06 17:28:08.029: I/HBAS(15090): 3

05-06 17:28:09.019: I/HBAS(15090): 14

05-06 17:28:09.979: I/HBAS(15090): 1
05-06 17:28:10.029: I/HBAS(15090): 5

05-06 17:28:10.989: I/HBAS(15090): 16

05-06 17:28:12.009: I/HBAS(15090): 17

05-06 17:28:12.999: I/HBAS(15090): 18

05-06 17:28:13.999: I/HBAS(15090): 19

05-06 17:28:14.999: I/HBAS(15090): 20

05-06 17:28:16.009: I/HBAS(15090): 21

05-06 17:28:17.009: I/HBAS(15090): 22

05-06 17:28:18.009: I/HBAS(15090): 23

05-06 17:28:19.019: I/HBAS(15090): 24

05-06 17:28:20.019: I/HBAS(15090): 25

05-06 17:28:21.029: I/HBAS(15090): 26

05-06 17:28:22.029: I/HBAS(15090): 27

05-06 17:28:23.029: I/HBAS(15090): 28

05-06 17:28:24.039: I/HBAS(15090): 29

05-06 17:28:25.039: I/HBAS(15090): 0

05-06 17:28:26.029: I/HBAS(15090): 1
05-06 17:28:26.069: I/HBAS(15090): 

05-06 17:28:26.069: D/AndroidRuntime(15090): Shutting down VM
05-06 17:28:26.069: W/dalvikvm(15090): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
05-06 17:28:26.079: E/AndroidRuntime(15090): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-06 17:28:26.079: E/AndroidRuntime(15090): java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
05-06 17:28:26.079: E/AndroidRuntime(15090):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:362)
05-06 17:28:26.079: E/AndroidRuntime(15090):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
05-06 17:28:26.079: E/AndroidRuntime(15090):    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:506)
05-06 17:28:26.079: E/AndroidRuntime(15090):    at com.android.hbas.FinalSetting$1.handleMessage(FinalSetting.java:362)
05-06 17:28:26.079: E/AndroidRuntime(15090):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-06 17:28:26.079: E/AndroidRuntime(15090):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-06 17:28:26.079: E/AndroidRuntime(15090):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
05-06 17:28:26.079: E/AndroidRuntime(15090):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-06 17:28:26.079: E/AndroidRuntime(15090):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-06 17:28:26.079: E/AndroidRuntime(15090):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
05-06 17:28:26.079: E/AndroidRuntime(15090):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
05-06 17:28:26.079: E/AndroidRuntime(15090):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

At start it worked but at some time it FC because of ' ' thing.
So any solution???
Thanks for the advice..

Comment: You should click the check mark next to his answer to accept it as the one that solved your issue.  That gives him credit and let's others know your issue has been sorted so they can skip over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your string is `' '` only.

```
    if(str.trim().length>0){

       try{ 

       int i =Integer.parseInt(str);

       }catch(NumberFormatException ne){
          System.out.println("could not parse :: " +ne);
        }

    }
```